# Find first visible input text with blank value having attribute required

Tags: jquery

I want to create a jQuery function for first visible input text with blank value having attribute required (without each function if doable).

```
$("input[type='text'][value='']").eq(0).on(function(){      
   // code    
});
```

Comment: `$(formId).find("input:first-child[type='text'][value='']")` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** and **[`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**

```js
$("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function() {
  return this.value.trim() == '';
}).eq(0).css('border', '1px solid red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" style="display:none">
<input type="text">
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required>
```

---

If value attribute is need to check then

```js
$("input[type='text']:visible[required][value='']").eq(0).css('border', '1px solid red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" style="display:none" value=''>
<input type="text" value=''>
<input type="text" value='' required>
<input type="text" value='' required>
```

Comment: thanks first one worked for me, but i want to create a jQuery function for further use like this :-             $("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function () {
                    return this.value.trim() == '';
                }).eq(0).on(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr('id'));
                });                                                                                                I am not sure what should I use "on" or any other function.

Comment: @SunilChaudhry : `function get(){ return $("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function() {
  return this.value.trim() == '';
}).eq(0); }`

Comment: sorry @PranavCBalan I think my question wasn't clear.  I want to use $(this) for further processing.

Comment: @SunilChaudhry :  just assign it to a variable `var $ele = return $("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function() { return this.value.trim() == ''; }).eq(0);` and use `$ele`....

Comment: its not working and showing error "return is not a function" and if I use this :-   var $ele= $("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function() { return this.value.trim() == ''; }).eq(0); // then getting undefind

Comment: @SunilChaudhry use `var $ele = $("input[type='text']:visible[required]").filter(function() { return this.value.trim() == ''; }).eq(0);`

Comment: thanks @PranavCBalan its working, actually I was using  alert($ele.id);  instead of alert($ele.attr('id')); .